# Cloudfront TTL settings: What happens with minimum TTL 0 when S3 object is updated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

If I have a custom object caching TTL setting for Cloudfront (connecting to an S3 bucket) where:

```
Min TTL: 0
Max TTL: 1 year
Default TTL: 1 week
```

My question is this:
If I update an object in S3, will Cloudfront immediately serve up the new object (assuming it had been previously stored in cache), or will it continue to serve up the cached item for up to 1 week as per the default TTL?

I assume with a 0 min ttl, that it would recognize it had been updated, but I can't find any documentation that makes this clear.

Second question:
Since this is a custom TTL, and the min is 0, does that mean that the object actually never gets cached? (Are we just ignoring the default and max in this case?)

Answer (score 1):

Minimum TTL is different than you suppose.

If an object fetched from the origin has a `Cache-Control: max-age=n` header where `n < minimum-ttl`, then CloudFront will ignore the `max-age=n` and instead cache the object for up to minimum-ttl.  A minimum-ttl set to 0 is essentially eqivalent to making minimum-ttl never applicable (until time travel is invented), since no object could have a declared max-age less than 0.

Maximum TTL is the same, on the other side, if `n > maximum-ttl`, then CloudFront will cache the object for not longer than maximum-ttl.

If no `Cache-Control: max-age=n` is not present, CloudFront will cache the object for not longer than default-ttl.

In any event, CloudFront will not check the origin again for a new version of an already-cached object until its TTL expires.  It gets no notification of changed objects from S3.  You can tell how long an object had been in a specific edge cache by inspecting the `Age:` response header.

If you need to evict an object early, use a cache invalidation.  An invalidation matches any object that matches the specified pattern (e.g. `/images/*` evicts any object matching that path) and an invalidation simply tells all the CloudFront edge caches that "if" they have any matching objects cached before the time of the eviction, those must be treated as invalid and no longer used to serve requests.  An invalidation succeeds regardless of whether any cached objects were found that matched the pattern.  It doesn't tell you what it evicted because -- presumably -- it doesn't literally purge them immediately, it just sets markers that prevents old matching cache entries from being used (forcing a re-fetch on the next request) and actually finds and purges them later, in the background.  You get 1,000 invalidation requests for free each month, where 1 invalidation request can include wildcards and evict millions of objects, but that still only counts as 1 invalidation.